# Problems with exporting blender model to Unity

Tags: export, unity

[image: Images from different perspectives][image: ""][image: ""[![][3]]][image]
I wanted to try out to export some Blender chess Models, to create a little chess game with Unity. With 2 of the Models, everything worked out fine, but the third is behaving weirdly. It seems like the model is always tilting, so that you see it from the same side all the time. Problem is, i made the models a few months ago, so I don't know exactly what I might have done differently in the third one. But as far as I remember, I made all of them the same way. I hope the 2 Images clarify what I mean/what my problem is (I only used the Hand Tool to show the different perspectives.

I'm working with Blender version 2.79 and Unity 2017.3.0f3 (Personal).
I exported all the models as .fbx file (only the mesh).

Comment: It would be really great if you show area of interest (objects in this case) when more zoomed in as well as cutting screenshot to that area. As to your object try applying scale and recalculating normals in Blender.

Comment: I made some other screenshots, and edited the question. I tried recalculating normals - didn't work. What do exactly you mean with "applying scale"?

Comment: @Mr Zak I tried recalculating normals again, now it did work, I don't know why it did'nt work, before (It was one of my first ideas, too). Thanks anyway!

Comment: It looks like your normals are inverted.